# Initialize a xml class obtained from Edit, Paste Special, Paste XML as Classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a class generated from "Edit, Paste Special, Paste XML as Classes." like explains [here. Generating Data Type Classes from XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Items version="1.0">
  <Item InputFileName="G:\FileFile.txt">
    <Position X="500" Y="100" Z="150"/>
  </Item>
</Items>
```

Class:

```
namespace Produccion.ClassFile
{
/// <comentarios/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class Items
{

    private ItemsItem[] itemField;

    private decimal versionField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Item")]
    public ItemsItem[] Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal version
    {
        get
        {
            return this.versionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.versionField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ItemsItem
{

    private ItemsItemPosition positionField;

    private string inputFileNameField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    public ItemsItemPosition Position
    {
        get
        {
            return this.positionField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.positionField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string InputFileName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.inputFileNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.inputFileNameField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <comentarios/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ItemsItemPosition
{

    private decimal xField;

    private decimal yField;

    private decimal zField;

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal X
    {
        get
        {
            return this.xField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.xField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Y
    {
        get
        {
            return this.yField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.yField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <comentarios/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public decimal Z
    {
        get
        {
            return this.zField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.zField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I don't know how I can initialize this class with data from file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Deserialization is the process of reading an XML document and constructing an object that is strongly typed to the XML Schema (XSD) of the document.

You would do something like this

```
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Items));

// Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
Items i;

using (Stream reader = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
{
    // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
    i = (Items)serializer.Deserialize(reader);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely an expert now...(Years later, a newbie answers) I couldn't find the solution to how to use Paste Special XML, I was getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".  This was when my XML had an attribute and an Element (I was using VB). I realized VS did not initialize the variable [Name]Field. So I just added As New for the [Name][Name] class. In your case, New ItemsItemPosition.

Comment: better later than never :), after 8 years two week ago I come back to this question because I needed again and now you write and another answer, this is amazing